# Ordered list in Django

Tags: django

Can anyone help, I want to return an ordered list based on forloop in Django using a field in the model that contains both integer and string in the format MM/1234. The loop should return the values with the least interger(1234) in ascending order in the html template.

Comment: Is this a model? Can you show sample data and (expected) output?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to change the model to have two fields, one integer and one string, so you can code a queryset with ordering based on the integer one. You can then define a property of the model to return the `self.MM+"/"+str( self.nn)` composite value if you often need to use that. But if it's somebody else's database schema, this may not be an option.

In which case you'll have to convert your queryset into a list (which reads all the data rows at once) and then sort the list in Python rather than in the database. You can run out of memory or bring your server to its knees if the list contains millions of objects. `count=qs.count()` is a DB operation that won't.

```
qs = Foo.objects.filter( your_selection_criteria)
# you might want to count this before the next step, and chicken out if too many 
# also this simple key function will crash if there's ever no "/" in that_field
all_obj = sorted( list( qs), 
            key = lambda obj: obj.that_field.split('/')[1] )
```